# How can I verify data uploaded to CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have dataset of 442k JSON documents in single ~2.13GB file in Azure Data Lake Store.

I've upload it to collection in CosmosDB via Azure Data Factory pipeline. Pipeline is completed successfully.

But when I went to CosmosDB in Azure Portal, I noticed that collection size is only 1.5 GB. I've tried to run `SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM c` for this collection, but it returns only 19k. I've also seen complains that this count function is not reliable.

If I open collection preview, first ~10 records match my expectations (ids and content are the same as in ADLS file).

Is there a way to quickly get real record count? Or some other way to be sure that nothing is lost during import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates), you could find:

> When using the Azure portal's Query Explorer, note that aggregation queries may return the partially aggregated results over a query page. The SDKs produces a single cumulative value across all pages.
>   In order to perform aggregation queries using code, you need .NET SDK 1.12.0, .NET Core SDK 1.1.0, or Java SDK 1.9.5 or above.

So I suggest you could firstly try to use azure documentdb sdk to get the count value.

More details about how to use , you could refer to this [article](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/).